# Change of Summation and Differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking explicitly for a proof that that infinite summation of sequence of functions, **uniformly convergent** and differentiation are interchangable.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f_n(x)$$
and an explicit example where pointwise convergent series fail to do so.

[THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147869/interchanging-the-order-of-differentiation-and-summation)  post has same question but no proof. The refered link in 3rd edition of rudin has related but different proof.

Comment: uniform convergence is not sufficient to switch limits and differentiation http://www.mathcs.org/analysis/reals/funseq/proofs/uconvdiff.html

Comment: the link you give lists several examples that show the uniform convergence does not imply differentiation and limits interchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical theorem is that if each $f_n$ and $f_n'$ are continuous on an interval, the series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)
$$
converges pointwise, and the series
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)
$$
converges uniformly, then $f$ is differentiable and $f' = g$.  This uses the fundamental theorem of calculus and the ability to interchange uniform limits with integrals.