# How can we show that $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}x^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> How can we show that$^\ast$ $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}x^n\color{blue}{=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}nx^{n-1}}\tag 1$$ for some fixed $x\in[0,1)$?

Clearly, $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}\tag 2$$ and hence, by a [well-known theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1140474/47771), it's sufficient to show that the rhs of $(1)$ is convergent. How can we do so?

---

$^\ast$ Let's define $0^0:=1$, $1/0:=\infty$ and $0\cdot\infty:=0$.

Comment: It's actually enough to show that the right side of (1) is uniformly convergent on $[0,r]$, for a given $r\in(0,1)$.

Comment: The theorem gives uniform convergence on every interval $[0, r]$, $0 < r < 1$, and hence convergence on $[0, 1)$, but it does not guarantee uniform convergence on the latter interval, and indeed, the convergence isn't uniform there.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right, I've updated the question.

Comment: Also, $x$ cannot belong to $[0,1)$ because $n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}.$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis I have no idea what you mean. $(2)$ is just a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: If $x\in [0,1)$ then for $x=0$ the sum can give $0^0$

Comment: @0xbadf00d $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: $0^0=1$ for most practical uses

Comment: @0xbadf00d Accually, $0^0=\frac{0}{0}$ that's why it's undefined. But if you "set" it, then ok

Comment: I've updated the question. We only need to show convergence of the rhs of $(1)$, cause $x$ is fixed and $(2)$ converges for that $x$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Let's define $0^0=1$, $1/0:=\infty$ and $0\cdot\infty=0$. Then the problem on the lhs of $(2)$ and the problem on the rhs of $(1)$ is solved.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Does that proof really exists ? Or it's just an axiom ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Which proof do you mean? Of the theorem? You can find it in the book mentioned in the link.

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, I'm taking about proving of $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}\frac{d}{dx}x^n.$$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Why should that proof not exist? Please take note of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by the answer and by the comments.

First, *when* we're talking about power series, it's an absolutely standard convention that $0^0=1$, so that $x^0$ depends continuously on $x$.

It's a well known theorem that if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ then $f'=g$ on $[a,b]$. Here, whether people say so or not, they mean to be talking about nondegenerate intervals, that is, they're considering the case $a<b$.

The well-known theorem also works for $[a,b)$, if $a<b$. But in the present case our series do not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

So we do this: Fix $r\in(0,1)$. Show that both series $\sum x^n$ and $\sum nx^{n-1}$ converge uniformly on $[0,r]$. Now the well-known theorem shows that $\frac d{dx}\sum x^n=\sum nx^{n-1}$ for every $x\in[0,r]$. This holds for every $r\in(0,1)$, and hence $\frac d{dx}\sum x^n=\sum nx^{n-1}$ on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Nice one, I think that answer is even stable

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}\;.$$ Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(1-x)S_n&=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k\\
&=\color{red}{1+}\sum_{k=\color{red}2}^nkx^{(k-1)}-\sum_{k=\color{red}2}^n\color{red}{k-1}x^{\color{red}{k-1}}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=2}^nx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k \stackrel{n\to\infty}\to\frac1{1-x}\;.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus, by the theorem mentioned in the question, $$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\frac1{1-x}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}x^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n\;.$$

Comment: Still, how $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}x^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}\frac{d}{dx}x^n.$$ ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis, OP actually proved that identity by showing that $$ \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n \geq 1} nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{d}{dx} x^n. $$ Of course this is not how we usually establish this kind of identity for general power series, but at least this proof is true.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis In words of the theorem: $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}y^n$ is differentiable for all $y\in [x,x]$ and is convergent for $y=x$. Moreover, I've proved that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}y^n$ is "uniformly" convergent on $[x,x]$ (i.e. the series is convergent for $y=x$). Thus, the theorem yields the desired statement.

Comment: @0xbadf00d well, ok. +1

Comment: @SangchulLee This is the easiest proof of the statement I could imagine. Any complex analysis tool would be an overkill here.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I didn't follow your answer. Your comment explains why - the version of the well-known theorem you're using is false. The well known theorem is valid for uniform convergence on $[a,b]$, where $a<b$. _As_ I said a few hours ago: It's sufficient to show the right side of (1) is uniformly convegent on $[0,r]$, for each $r\in(0,1)$.