# derivative of infinite sum of terms

Tags: derivatives

If we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)$ and assume this is a convergent sum and asumme all the $f_i$ are differentiable in every point. Is the derivative of the infinite sum equal to the sum of the derivatives (so is $(\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x))' = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f'_i(x)$ ) ?

Comment: I don't believe that is always true, you need to put some conditions on the sequence $f_i$ to be able to do that.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147869/interchanging-the-order-of-differentiation-and-summation

Answer (score 1):

This is called "differentiation term-by-term".  You can come up with examples where it fails.  But in many cases it is correct.  The best known case is the power series.  In that case, differentiation term-by-term holds inside the radius of convergence.

Another one is due to [Fubini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation) ... if all $f_i$ are increasing, then term-by-term differentiation holds almost everywhere.