# Principles of integrating/differentiating infinite sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives

In which cases is it allowed to distribute integration/differentiation sign over an infinite sum? Per se, to perform the following operation(analogically for the differentiation as well).
$$\int\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x) dx\ =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int f_i(x) dx\ $$

Particularly it is quite popular to apply this rule to the expansion of geometric series: e.i. $ \frac{1}{1-x}$

Note:

I know that it can happen that all member functions of the series to be differentiable, yet the sum be nowhere differentiable(Weierstrass function) or even vice versa. So I am wandering if there is a theorem or a heuristic according to which one can decide whether that operation is allowed to perform or not.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147869/interchanging-the-order-of-differentiation-and-summation).

Comment: I would appreciate if you would elaborate on both of them

Comment: thanks and what about the differentiation?

Comment: Ok thanks I will wait for your answer

Comment: Yeah I know that too but I guess it is not the only condition. I guess it should be broader