# Derivative of series and series of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Let $f_n(x)$ be real functions. Given that the derivatives exist, and that the sums converge, is the following true? If not, what is a counterexample, and when is it true?

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/147869/

Comment: This does not happen in all cases, but if your RHS converges at least locally uniformly then the equality is true.