# Finding result of composing operations many times

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory

Consider the operator given by,

$$ P = x \frac{d}{dx}$$

with,

$$ P^2 = x \frac{d}{dx} ( x\frac{d}{dx}) = x \frac{d}{dx} + x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$

or,

$$ P^2 = x \frac{d}{dx} ( x\frac{d}{dx}) = x \frac{d}{dx} + x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$

and on another application of the operator,

$$ P^3 = [x \frac{d}{dx}] P^2 = x\frac{d}{dx}(x \frac{d}{dx}) + x \frac{d}{dx}( x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}) = x \frac{d}{dx} + 3x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x^3 \frac{d^3}{dx^3}  $$

I tried writing more iterations but I can't find / a general form of what $P^k$ should be. So my question is if you are given an operator as the one shown, is there any standard procedure to find the a formula for the kth iteration of the operator?

[The actual reason why I want to know about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802620/finding-a-general-way-to-sum-sum-i-1i-n-ik-for-a-given-k-using-eleme?noredirect=1#comment7837062_3802620)

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $x\frac{d}{dx}$? What is $\frac{d}{dx}$ the derivative of? Do you mean sometthing like $x\frac{dy}{dx}$? Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by $P^2$ etc. Do you mean differentiating $P$ with respect to $x$ and you're simply writing it as $P^2$?

Comment: It is inspired by heaviside's operator method of solving differential equations
https://www.math24.net/differential-operators/#:~:text=Differential%20operators%20are%20a%20generalization,first%20derivative%20of%20this%20function%3A&text=Double%20D%20allows%20to%20obtain,y%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2(x).

Comment: @A-levelStudent It seems clear to me that $P=xD$ is the variable $x$ right-multiplied by the associated differential operator. This is a well-defined differential operator.

Comment: @PeterForeman ok, I obviously haven't encountered it yet, apologies for my ignorance :)

Comment: Related: [Exponential of a function times derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719487/exponential-of-a-function-times-derivative). Especially:
$$
\left[1 + x\frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^3 + \cdots\right] f(x) = e^{x\frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f(e\,x)
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coefficients are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

We can write
$$P^n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}x^k D^k$$
where $D=\frac d{dx}$. Then
$$P^{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}(xD)(x^k D^k)
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}(kx^k D^k+ x^{k+1} D^{k+1})$$
so that
$$a_{n+1,1}=a_{n,1},$$
$$a_{n+1,n+1}=a_{n,n}$$
and
$$a_{n+1,k}=a_{n,k-1}+ka_{n,k}$$
These recurrences are the same as for the Stirling numbers, so
$$a_{n,k}=S(n,k).$$

Comment: I think you mean $x^k$

Comment: (+1) Very interesting that these numbers appear here!

Comment: That is very interesting indeed, but what does it mean? Like, what does it mean that the co-efficents are stirling numbers, is there some deeper meaning or is this an abstract result

Comment: How did you know that such a series existed for  the jth composition of that operator