# Deriving iterative applications of an operator using recursion

Tags: operator-theory

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3802748/688539) by Angina Seng, they start with the proposition that:

$$ P^n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k} x^k D^k$$

Why were they able to do this? Is there any easy justification to give for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a general fact about the [Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) $k[x, D]$ (where $D = \partial_x$) that every element can be written this way. The proof is just by induction; you apply the canonical commutation relation $D x - x D = 1$ a lot to move $x$'s past $D$'s. As a simple example,

$$(xD)^2 = x(Dx)D = x(xD + 1)D = x^2 D^2 + xD.$$

In general, it suffices to show that $D^i x^j$ can be written as a sum of terms of the form $x^k D^{\ell}$, which you do by commuting the $k$ copies of $x$ past the $j$ copies of $D$ using the canonical commutation relation. It will be convenient to adopt the notation $[X, Y] = XY - YX$ and to prove lemmas about it, e.g. that it's a derivation in each variable, and a lemma about what $[X, Y^n]$ looks like.

Abstractly you can get this out of the [Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem), applied to the universal enveloping algebra of the [Heisenberg algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Lie_algebra) $\text{span}(x, D, 1)$. (You then need to take a quotient of the universal enveloping algebra given by setting $1$ to the identity to get the Weyl algebra.)

Comment: How did you get the canonical commutation relation? It just seems unbelievable for that to be true

Comment: @Buraian: it's a straightforward application of the product rule. If $f$ is, say, any smooth function then we are just saying that $D(xf) = f + x D(f)$.

Comment: $(xD)^2 = x(Dx)D$

How did you get this? $(xD)^2 = (xD)(xD)$, 

By the commutator $xD=Dx-1$ , plugging that

$(xD)^2 =xD(Dx)$

Comment: @Buraian: that's associativity. Your last equation is incorrect; we have $(xD)^2 = (xD)(xD) = (xD)(Dx - 1) = x D^2 x - xD$. That's true but it's not relevant to what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: Got it now, thank you.. Very nteresting result.