# On computing $\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)x^{k}$

Tags: calculus, power-series, geometric-series

Let $x\in(0,1)$. My goal is to compute this well known almost-geometric series. $$\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)x^{k}$$

I've computed it using two similar methods, leading to different results. That pineapple brain of mine can't find the error.

**method 1 :**

\begin{align}
\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)x^{k}=& \sum_{k\geq-1}(k+1)x^{k} && \text{since }k=-1\Rightarrow (-1+1)x^{-1}=0 \\
=&\sum_{\tilde{k}\geq0}\tilde{k}\cdot x^{\tilde{k}-1} && \text{letting } \tilde{k}-1=k\\
=&\sum_{\tilde{k}\geq0}\frac{d}{dx}x^{\tilde{k}}\\
=&\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{\tilde{k}\geq0}x^{\tilde{k}}
\end{align}

which is the derivative of an easily-computable geometric series.

**method 2 :**

\begin{align}
\sum_{k\geq0}(k+1)x^{k}=& 1 + \sum_{k\geq1}(k+1)x^{k} && \text{since }k=0\Rightarrow (0+1)x^0=1 \\
=& 1 + \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k\geq1}x^{k+1}\\
=& 1 + \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k\geq1}x^{k+1} \\
=& 1 + \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{\tilde{k}\geq0}x^{\tilde{k}} && \text{letting } \tilde{k}-1=k\\
\end{align}

And a $1$ has been created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge 1}x^{k+1}=\sum_{\bar k\ge 0} x^{\bar k+2}\ne\sum_{\bar k\ge 0} x^{\bar k}$, the last step.

Comment: In your last formula $\tilde k$ should start at $2$ and not $0$.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why don't you simply write that $\;\sum\limits_{k\geq0}(k+1)x^{k}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum\limits_{k\geq 0}x^{k}$?

Comment: To rigorously change the derivative and the series, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147882/631742

Comment: @Bernard Simply because $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k\geq0}x^k = \sum_{k\geq0}k\cdot x^{(k-1)}$ wich isn't immediatly trivial to me that it is indeed $\sum_{(k\geq0)}(k+1)x^k$. Thanks for your concern and your advice.

Comment: Thank you @MaximilianJanisch